# Attach meta data to the GstBuffer

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I need to attach some meta data to the `GstBuffer` which provided by my `GstElement` pad. I know that there is a way to use `GstMetaInfo` and `gst_buffer_add_meta`. But this method involves using the same `MyCustomMetaData` class both in the code of my `GstElement` and in the code that actually receives the buffer. Which is undesirable for certain reasons. How could it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add metadata to the buffer:

```
static const gchar* tags[] = { NULL };
auto meta_info = gst_meta_register_custom ("mymeta", tags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
auto meta = gst_buffer_add_custom_meta (*buf, "mymeta");
auto metadata = gst_custom_meta_get_structure (meta);
gst_structure_set (metadata, "property_name", G_TYPE_INT64, gint64(1), nullptr);
```

Retrive metadata from the buffer:

```
auto meta = gst_buffer_get_custom_meta (buffer, "mymeta");
auto metadata = gst_custom_meta_get_structure (meta);
gint64 property;
gst_structure_get_int64 (metadata, "property_name", &property);
```